# Inconsistent rendering of documentation links on Meta.SO

Tags: bug, documentation, hyperlinks, markdown-rendering

Documentation links on Meta.SO do not render differently from other links, but the editor's preview shows them with the extra icon:

**Preview:**
[image: Preview]

**Final version:**
[image: Final version]

**They should be consistent:** either show the icon in the final rendering, or make sure that the preview is aware there should be no icon.

Comment: A probably related issue: [Links to documentation aren't rendered properly](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329130/1591669)