# Links to documentation aren't rendered properly

Tags: bug, documentation, markdown, hyperlinks, markdown-rendering

In documentation, when linking to a different topic / example, links aren't rendered properly.

If a raw link is added in a example, like this:

> `https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/186/functions/720/arrow-functions#t=201607221405479834123`

The editor preview shows a nicely formatted link, like this:

> [Arrow Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/186/functions/720/arrow-functions#t=201607221405479834123)

However, the actual page, when the edit is applied, shows the raw url:

> https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/186/functions/720/arrow-functions#t=201607221405479834123

The rendered result is easily fixed by manually setting the text for the reference, as I've done in [this proposed change](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/40047).
However, the preview window and the rendered result should be the same.

---

When linking to (Meta.)SO topics, this works as intended in both preview and rendered result:
[Links to documentation aren't rendered properly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329130/links-to-documentation-arent-rendered-properly)

Comment: Also, the preview of docs links in Q&A shows an icon next to the link, but the render doesn't.

Comment: @davidism: see [Inconsistent rendering of documentation links on Meta.SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329008/1591669)